# Laravel 4 link_to_action

Tags: laravel-4, link-to, actioncontroller

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to create a link to run my destroy action. Reading the documentation of Laravel 4, it should perform as follows:

```
link_to_action cast ('@ getIndex HomeController', $ title, $ parameters = array (), $ attributes = array ());
```

My code:

```
{{Link_to_action ('CompaniesController @ destroy', 'Test', array ($ company-> id), array ('class' => 'btn btn btn-sm-info'))}}
```

But when I got to the link, it redirects me to show the controller action, when the action should send me to destroy.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel -4 use this. You are following laravel 3 format:

```
{{ HTML::linkAction('CompaniesController@destroy', 'Test' , array ('class' => 'btn btn btn-sm-info')) }}
```

Comment: following his indication the code is as follows:

{{HTML :: linkAction ('CompaniesController @ destroy', 'Test', array ($ company-> id), array ('class' => 'btn btn btn-sm-info'))}}

but equally it is redirecting the show method ....

my destroy method is as follows:

public function destroy ($ id)
{
$ this-> company-> find ($ id) -> delete ();

return Redirect :: route ('companies.index');
}

have to do something in the routes file?

so is my file: Route :: resource ('companies', 'CompaniesController');

Thank you.

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: go to the destroy method, but without using a Form :: submit, is that I work with Ruby on Rails and in this language can create a link to delete my records, so I want to do something similar

Answer (score 0):

that method is generate a html element, and it have not DELETE method, you need a form with DELETE method to do that

Comment: laravel four generator: scaffold, believe in it the following form to delete the record:

  {{Form :: open (array ('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array ('companies.destroy', $ company-> id)))}}
                             {{Form :: submit ('Delete', array ('class' => 'btn btn-danger'))}}
                         {{Form :: close ()}}

Turns out to optimize the code would do with linkAction but what I see does not work, always brings me to the show method when the link clearly indicated that you go to the destroy method ... :/